# conda install -c conda-forge python-pdal Solving environment: | hangs when running windows 10

Tags: python, conda, freeze, pdal

Trying to install PDAL with conda and it just hangs at the "Solving Environment:"  I have not had much luck with PDAL.  I am using windows 10 and this is a fresh install of Anaconda / conda.  I let it run for about an hour just in case.  I was going to test some other "popular" package that may work to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below command to install pdal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdal
```

Please refer to: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdal

Comment: Glad to hear that this has helped you. Please consider accepting this answer in order to mark this thread as answered so when someone searches for a similar problem will see that this question is solved and they can find some help in here.

Comment: Do note that the accepted solution does not install the Python extension, if that was what you were looking for. Your original attempt _should_ have installed both the `pdal` and the `python-pdal` package. If you can replicate the original problem and post a ticket [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-pdal-feedstock/issues/new) we could take a closer look at the issue. Honestly, if it seemed to be hanging on "Solving Environment" I'd be inclined to simply cancel and try again, sounds more like a network error of some sort.