# Unable to install xgboost in python-3.7.0 version in anaconda propmt windows 10

Tags: python-3.7

[Image of python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWMJZ.png)I have installed anaconda and installed python 3.7.0 version in that and trying to install xgboost for python, it is showing "**Solving environment**" for a long time nothing is done yet. Can anyone tell me what can be done for this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing with the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Looks like there is a similar question here: 
[conda install -c conda-forge python-pdal Solving environment: | hangs when running windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477219/conda-install-c-conda-forge-python-pdal-solving-environment-hangs-when-runni)